# Spring Data Neo4j unrecognized field/property

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, lombok, fasterxml, neo4j-ogm

I ran SDN4-University a month ago fine. I copied parts to a new Spring Boot app to learn more. I could init the DB and persist objects, and added Lombok for autogeneration.

Another project ramped up, so Neo4j/SDN sat on the shelf... until last night.

SDN4-university still runs, but now my code now throws an exception about an unrecognized field/property just trying to persist a simple object.

I compared the two maven POMs, but nothing jumped out as significantly different.

```
2016-04-22 12:09:09.347  INFO o.n.o.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest 
  : POST http://neo4j@localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit, 
    request {
    "statements":[{"statement":"UNWIND {rows} as row 
       CREATE (n:`SpaceSummary`) 
       SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as nodeRef, ID(n) as nodeId",
    "parameters":{"rows":[{"nodeRef":-2039652805,
                           "props":{"title":"Timo Space","key":"TS"} }
                          ] },
    "resultDataContents":["row"],
    "includeStats":false}
    ]}
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: 
  Unrecognized field "meta" (class org.neo4j.ogm.result.ResultRowModel), 
  not marked as ignorable (one known property: "row"])
 at org.neo4j.ogm.result.ResultRowModel["meta"])
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from 
    (UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:51)
```

Comment: Are you using Neo4j 3? If so, please try using neo4j-ogm 2.0.1

Comment: Thanks. Yes, using Neo4j3. Turns out that updating to Spring Boot 1.4.0M2 pulled in all the most recent dependencies and it started working again.